# Swift 4 - SwiftyJson compare array and merge found values

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have a `JSON` object which contains a list of names and values. I want to compare to it another array `[String]` and if the value is found in one of the `JSON` object value merge that value to a new object.

I have tried using `merge(with)` in a `for` loop however, it seems to be merge just one value.

> ```
> > example:
> > 
> >  json_cat = 
> >     
> >     {
> >       name: "aaa",
> >       surname: "aaa-1",
> >       grade: "aaa-2"
> >     },
> >     {
> >       name: "bbb",
> >       surname: "bbb-1",
> >       grade: "bbb-2"
> >     },
> >     {
> >       name: "ccc",
> >       surname: "ccc-1",
> >       grade: "ccc-2"
> >     }
> >     
> //
> >     let arraytest:[String] = ["aaa", "ccc", "ddd"]
> > 
> // array   json_cat compare arraytest
> >     result = {
> >       name: "aaa",
> >       surname: "aaa-1",
> >       grade: "aaa-2"
> >     },
> >     {
> >       name: "ccc",
> >       surname: "ccc-1",
> >       grade: "ccc-2"
> >     }
> ```

```
let json_cat: JSON = "json from url" 
let arraytest:[String] = ["aaa", "ccc", "ddd"]
var json_cat_array = JSON()

    json_cat.forEach({ (index, json_p) in
                    if arraytest.contains(json_p["name"].string!) {
                        //print("\(index) - \(json_p)")
                        try! json_cat_array.merge(with: json_p)

                    }
                })
```

Comment: did u try `append`?

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your loop like this:

```
json_cat.forEach({ (index, json_p) in
    if arraytest.contains(json_p["name"].string!) {
        //print("\(index) - \(json_p)")

        json_cat_array[json_p["name"].string!] = json_p

    }
})
```

The merge function is really for merging data. Like in this example:

```
let original: JSON = [
    "first_name": "John",
    "age": 20,
    "skills": ["Coding", "Reading"],
    "address": [
        "street": "Front St",
        "zip": "12345",
    ]
]

let update: JSON = [
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "age": 21,
    "skills": ["Writing"],
    "address": [
        "zip": "12342",
        "city": "New York City"
    ]
]

let updated = original.merge(with: update)
// [
//     "first_name": "John",
//     "last_name": "Doe",
//     "age": 21,
//     "skills": ["Coding", "Reading", "Writing"],
//     "address": [
//         "street": "Front St",
//         "zip": "12342",
//         "city": "New York City"
//     ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code uses Swift 4 foundation JSON parser. Swift 4 has got wonder parser by default.

```
import Foundation
let jsonString = """
        [{
        "surname": "Roxxy",
        "grade": "neaou"
        },
        {
        "name": "Puffi",
        "surname": "Chips",
        "grade": "meaou"
        },
        {
        "name": "Taffy",
        "surname": "Baby",
        "grade": "mew-mew"
        }]
"""
struct JsonCat: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let surname: String
    let grade: String
}

struct Cat {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let grade: String
}


guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8), let jsonCats = try? JSONDecoder().decode([JsonCat].self, from: jsonData) else {
    fatalError()
}

var cats: [Cat] = []
jsonCats.forEach { jsonCat in
    guard let name = jsonCat.name else {
        return
    }
    let cat = Cat(name: name, surname: jsonCat.surname, grade: jsonCat.grade)
    cats.append(cat)
}

print(cats)
```